# How to read multiple text files into arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, text-files

I have multiple text files, each containing several columns. I need to read each file into an array in python, called RDF. The point is that I used to read **one** file into **one** array as following:

```
RDF_1 = numpy.loadtxt("filename_1.txt", skiprows=205, usecols=(1,), unpak=True)
```

How to create a loop in python such that it reads more than one file into their corresponding arrays like this:

```
for i in range(100):
    RDF_i =  numpy.loadtxt("filename_"+str(i)+".txt", skiprows=205, usecols=(1,), unpak=True)
```

Comment: This is a really bad way to code - your variable names should not be created dynamically

Comment: Can you provide a higher level context to what you are trying to achieve? I don't think you need to store the results of `numpy.loadtxt` inside a variable each time -- you are risking reading a lot of information into memory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: Do yu really want to use `unpack`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it. I use [two dimensional arrys](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) after importing numpy library.

However, I had to zero the arrays before filling them out with data because python had already filled them out with random values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionaries as a proper way:

```
files_mapping = dict()
for i in range(100):
    files_mapping[f'RDF_{i}'] = numpy.loadtxt(f"filename_{i}.txt", skiprows=205, usecols=(1,), unpak=True)
```

But if for some unknown reasons you really need to dynamically create variables then you can use [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

```
for i in range(100):
    exac(f'RDF_{i} = numpy.loadtxt(f"filename_{i}.txt", skiprows=205, usecols=(1,), unpak=True)'
```

And another possible way is using [locals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals):

```
for i in range(100):
    locals()[f'RDF_{i}'] = numpy.loadtxt(f"filename_{i}.txt", skiprows=205, usecols=(1,), unpak=True)
```

You need to avoid using two last options in real code because it's a direct way to spawning hard-to-find bugs.